# How can mouse clicks stop working in Windows but I can move the mouse?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, microsoft-powerpoint

**Situation:**

- Windows 2008 Server with SP2 64 Bit used as "Terminal Server", Direct X 11
- Office 2007 32 Bit
- .net add-in for PowerPoint using WPF, nlog, Lucene
- the add-in is for end-users and does not require RDP (this particular client uses terminal server)

**Complication:**

- **After starting PowerPoint (with the add-in loading) mouse clicks are not working any more**
- the mouse cursor keeps moving, the machine is generally responsive
- the behavior persists even after killing the PowerPoint process
- the behavior persists even after re-connecting to the terminal session
- the only way to restore the mouse clicks is by terminating the session

**Solutions**

- How to diagnose why Windows stops receiving Mouse clicks?
- What are possible causes for this (drivers, display, RDP etc.)

Unfortunately the behavior does not reproduce on a test system.

Comment: +1 for the question, having the same issue when logging in to the workstation locally after RDP session. My money is on RDP HID driver bug. It's very rare issue though.

Comment: Thanks, I'm no expert in RDP. Would you know a way to circumvent RDP?  Can we reset the RDP HID driver?

Comment: I don't know of a way to do that. Probably, the best thing we can do is keep installing all MS updates on both client and server. I'm working through RDP most of the time and faced many input and graphics issues, some of them being gone after updates.

Comment: Could you please clarify the reproduction scenario?  Have you tried running your application directly on Windows rather than through a Remote Desktop?  If it needs the RDP connection, then you're asking the wrong community and should look at some of the systemic sites instead.

Comment: @cyberj0g The add-in is for end-users and does not require RDP, just this particular client uses terminal server. With the test system we we trying to use the same office, windows and connection.

Answer (score 7):

This is probably due to WPF bug https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ac81b552-44ac-4410-a5cd-4dbf6132a634/wpf-apps-stop-responding-to-touches-while-mouse-continues-to-work?forum=wpf

Recommendations are the following:

- upgrade OS
- upgrade Office (2007 is way too old, also 32 bit may be incompatible with 64 bit OS).
- check that the client uses latest RDP client as well (Windows 7/8 has a different RDP client than, say, Windows XP)
- test the behaviour with same client on the test platform.

Also, quick fix for you (if this is a business-cirtical situation) - if the problem exists only for one client, and you need to fix it ASAP, install VNC server on the Win server and let the client use VNC (RealVNC, for example).

Comment: A WPF bug might be the cause, but in the bug you link mouse clicks explicitly keep working. Thanks for the time to offer these recommendations. Of course we would prefer any of the first 3 solutions, but those are not under our control. Also VNC is no option since the end users are accustomed to connecting through normal RDP.

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft Tech Support solved a similar problem for me by suggesting downloading Remote Desktop Connection Manager v2.7, which I now use as my RDP client.  In addition to solving the mouse click bug, it allows scaling of the terminal window, like VNC.